# Save NuGet feed credentials in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, teamcity

I've setup the NuGet server in TeamCity 10 and configured it to only allow authenticated users to use it.  In Visual Studio, I added the TeamCity feed via Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Sources.  This works fine and when prompted for my credentials I enter them and check the box to Save them, but that only lasts until I close Visual Studio.  The next time I open it and VS tries to do anything with NuGet, I'm prompted again.

How do I really get VS to save the credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @wendys answer, i just had to download the latest nuget.exe and run

```
.\NuGet.exe sources update -name <myTeamCitySourceName>-src https://companyTeamCityServer:8443/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc -username <your_TC_username> -password <your_TC_pwd>
```

Which modifies the file Wendy mentions, but hashes the password and also ensures the credentials are not removed during a rebuild of the solution (which is what happened if i manually edited the nuget.config file).

Answer (score 1):

Please set your NuGet Feed Credentials in NuGet.Config file which stored under path "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet".

For example, the TeamCity feed you added into Visual Studio 2015 named "TeamCityFeed". Then please add following credential node in NuGet.Config as below.

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
<TeamCityFeed>
  <add key="Username" value="Your Feed User Name" />
  <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="Your Password" />
</TeamCityFeed>
```

Then please close your Visual Studio 2015 and open it again **as administrator**.

Comment: This set me on the path to figure out which file to modify, but my manual changes were lost on each rebuild.  (And i'm not about to start running VS as admin by default).